# How to animate the movement of multiple shapes using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, shapes

I'm aiming to recreate this sort of project that i've found made in Flash, using the canvas tag.

This is the project that i want to replicate:
https://www.kongregate.com/games/Stillmerlin/the-empty-kingdom

I am finding it difficult to understand how to animate the movement of the shapes when they have to escape from the visual field.

this is the code that I have compiled for the moment, I managed to move the square inside the various rectangles using the keyboard: https://jsfiddle.net/mgus17db/

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("#demo_canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pg = canvas.getContext("2d");

var xPos = 75;
var yPos = 75;

function draw() {
 ctx.rect(50, 50, 150, 100);
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.rect(250, 50, 150, 100);
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.rect(450, 50, 150, 100);
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.rect(250, 200, 150, 100);
 ctx.stroke();

 pg.rect(xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
 pg.stroke();
};

draw();
console.log("x = " + xPos + ", y = " + yPos);


function move(e) {

 //ARROW KEY RIGHT
 if (e.keyCode == 39) {
  if (xPos == 75 && yPos == 75) {
   xPos += 225;
  }
  else if (xPos == 300 && yPos == 75) {
   xPos += 225;
  };
 };

 //ARROW KEY LEFT
 if (e.keyCode == 37) {
  if (xPos == 75 && yPos == 75) {
   xPos -= 0;
  }
  else if (xPos == 300 && yPos == 75) {
   xPos -= 225;
  }
  else if (xPos == 525 && yPos == 75) {
   xPos -= 225;
  };
 };

 //ARROW KEY UP
 if (e.keyCode == 38) {
  if (yPos == 75) {
   yPos -= 0;
  }
  else if (yPos == 225) {
   yPos -= 150;
  }
 };

 //ARROW KEY DOWN
 if (e.keyCode == 40) {
  if (yPos == 75 && xPos == 300) {
   yPos += 150;
  }
 };

 canvas.width = canvas.width;
 draw();
 console.log("x = " + xPos + ", y = " + yPos);
};

document.onkeydown = move;
```

Comment: can you **describe the flash animation you want to achieve**? (I can't view the link for some reason, even though i have flash player installed). From looking at your code it looks like you just have to accomodate for if the x/y positions go out of the window in your if/else conditions, e.g. ``else if (xPos <= 0 || xPos > 525) {
            xPos = 75;
        } `` . But as I can't see what you're trying to reproduce, I don't know if that's the [whole] solution to your problem..

Comment: hi, i made a video for you so u can see exactly what i want to achieve: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AKwMVicBgygxvskzT537em1eKJcgYezA/view

Comment: Hi I just looked at the video (which was quite different than I expected). Do you have a set of images that you're working with?  I'm thinking you could probably use keyframes/ transforms/ css3 animations.. I don't really have the time tonight to spend on it but will have a look. Try out some animations. If you have an image set, that'd help lots!

Comment: i will try, thank you!

Comment: How did you get on? Did you make any progress? You may find [this link](https://itnext.io/creating-css-animations-using-sprite-sheet-47e2b7a3793c) helpful (relating to animations) In his given sample fiddles, e.g.[this one](https://jsfiddle.net/thatisuday/sqjsLjyh/), the property background-position-x is highlighted in red in jsfiddle (which usually indicates a mistake), but [it's correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position-x)